# how to update .env file in production while Jenkins deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

how to update the .env file in production while Jenkins deployment?
we have not committed the .env file in git for security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store secret file at Jenkins and use it for deployment.
It can be achieved by using [Credentials](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/) and [Credentials Binding](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/) plugins.

1. Install Credentials Binding and Credentials plugins
2. Select your user name in the top navigation bar.
3. Select Credentials in the left pane.
4. Under Stores from parent, select (global) in the Domains column.
5. Select Add Credentials in the left pane.
   [image]
6. insert into your pipeline script

```
  
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'env', variable: 'mySecretEnvFile')]){
    sh 'cp $mySecretEnvFile $WORKSPACE'
}
```